# SVD in linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svd

I was reading the book [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) and came across the section that tried to interpret ridge regression using singular value decomposition (SVD) of the design matrix, $X$. Specifically, I found the following:

$X=UDV^{T}$, where matrix $U$ is $N\times p$, $V$ is a $p\times p$ orthogonal matrix, and $D$ is a $p\times p$ diagonal matrix.

I am confused because from Wikipedia, the orthogonal matrix has to be a square matrix. In this case matrix $U$ does not qualify. Later I tend to believe that $U$ contains orthogonal columns only, and that results in $U^{T}U=I$, but $UU^{T}\ne I$. This seems to make sense because I found in the book

$X \hat{\beta}=X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y=UU^{T}Y$, and $UU^{T}Y$ should not be equal to $Y$

So my question becomes: are there two versions of SVD I can do? One results in both $U$ and $V$ being orthogonal and square matrix, and the other like this? Or is there anything wrong with my argument?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Update after receiving initial answer:

After reading @BabakP 's answer, I thought testing the algorithm using software is a good idea. So I tried svd function in Matlab. The result shows a square U matrix in dimension NxN, a diagonal matrix D in dimension Nxp, and a square V matrix in dimension pxp. Example below:

```
A=[ones(10,1) randn(10,1)];
[U,S,V]=svd(A);
>> size(U)

ans =

10    10

>> size(S)

ans =

10     2

>> size(V)

ans =

 2     2
```

So does this mean R and Matlab give two different versions?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is only one version of SVD. The correct dimensions for an SVD decomposition are $N\times p_1$, $p_1\times p_2$ and $M\times p_2$, this makes sense because you want the product of the three matrices to be (a reconstruction of) the original matrix. So if $X$ is $N\times M$, so should the reconstruction be, or to put it differently:

$$N \times M = (N \times p_1) \times (p_1 \times p_2) \times (M \times p_2)^T$$

Edit: usually, $p_1 = p_2 = p$, resulting in a square matrix (like in Matlab)

The orthogonal, rectangular matrices contain left and right singular vectors respectively and the middle, rectangular matrix contains the singular values on the diagonal.

Edit2: (see comments)

```
A=[ones(10,1) randn(10,20)];

[U,S,V] = svd(A);
errors = zeros(10,1);
for p = 10:-1:1
    err = U(:,1:p) * S(1:p,1:p) * V(:,1:p)' - A;
    errors(p) = sum(sum(err.*err));
end
plot(errors);
ylabel('Squared error');
xlabel('p');
```

[image]

Comment: Do we need symbol 'p' in the example? I thought one version is (if X is NxM), U: NxM, D: MxM, V: MxM. I have found references associated with this version, but still references with alternative explanation like this (http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm). Do you happen to know why?

Comment: SVD is used (amongst other uses) as a preprocessing step to reduce the amount of dimensions for your learning algorithm. This why you would introduce a choice of $p << M$, which basically allows you to learn in the reduced $p$-dimensional space. Here, $p$ is a design choice. If you are familiar with PCA (which I recommend you should be), this would be the equivalent of dropping the $M-k$ least important eigenvectors. Setting $p$ equal to the original dimensions asin your example, allows for a flawless reconstruction, but no dimensionality reduction.

Comment: yes, I understood your argument.

Comment: Great, could you mark this question as answered/closed?

Comment: I agree there is link between SVD and PCA. But both versions I found allows flawless reconstruction, and they output U matrix of different dimensions. By the way, in your equation, shouldn't p1 be set equal to N rather than p2 to make U as a square matrix like the Matlab example I posted? That's a typo, right? I haven't closed the question as I am still not 100% clear on it.

Comment: Again, it's really a design choice, you can choose $p_1$, $p_2$ or $p$ to be whatever you want depending on the purpose of the decomposition. You may choose $p_1=N$ and $p_2=M$, revealing the flawless reconstruction case. Choosing $p_1=p_2=p$ will force the middle matrix to be square and ensures that both new bases have the same dimension. Choosing $p$ lower than your original dimensions almost always results in loss of information (unless you have redundant dimensions).  (e.g. try it out with the code provided in my second edit)

Comment: thanks for this example and I believe it shows that by choosing p1 less than N, we can reduce dimensions at the cost of acceptable approximation error, as your figure suggests. However, my point is, even if p1 is not selected equal to N, we may still have flawless reconstruction. I have figured out that SVD decomposition is NOT unique. You can check the link (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SingularValueDecomposition.html) here. It defines both versions of U matrix. Both achieve flawless reconstruction. That explains why we have two kinds of outcome in R and Matlab.

Comment: I did not see this particular form before, but an SVD is unique up to a unit-phase factor (complex case) or a sign (real case) except for very special degenerate cases. As such I think both versions are the same. All in all it seems to be a matter of notation (remember that since the middle matrix only contains elements on the diagonal, 'abundant' rows/columns have only zeros and will be dropped).

Answer (score 1):

Here is some R code that validates your formulas given above:

```
#Generate psuedo data
Y = rnorm(10)
X = matrix(c(rep(1,10),rnorm(10)),ncol=2)

#Calculate X times beta hat
XB1 = X%*%solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y

#Make sure X = UDV'
svd(X)$u%*%diag(svd(X)$d)%*%t(svd(X)$v)

> svd(X)$u%*%diag(svd(X)$d)%*%t(svd(X)$v)
      [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]    1 -0.20283033
 [2,]    1 -0.85846798
 [3,]    1  0.07970559
 [4,]    1 -0.28254373
 [5,]    1  0.39261439
 [6,]    1 -0.31559482
 [7,]    1  0.20561526
 [8,]    1  0.55152336
 [9,]    1 -0.69396930
[10,]    1 -1.21970880
> X
      [,1]        [,2]
 [1,]    1 -0.20283033
 [2,]    1 -0.85846798
 [3,]    1  0.07970559
 [4,]    1 -0.28254373
 [5,]    1  0.39261439
 [6,]    1 -0.31559482
 [7,]    1  0.20561526
 [8,]    1  0.55152336
 [9,]    1 -0.69396930
[10,]    1 -1.21970880


#Calculate UU'Y
U = svd(X)$u
XB2 = U%*%t(U)%*%Y

#Check to see if they return the same thing
cbind(XB1,XB2)

> cbind(XB1,XB2)
            [,1]       [,2]
 [1,] -0.4644321 -0.4644321
 [2,] -0.7215807 -0.7215807
 [3,] -0.3536183 -0.3536183
 [4,] -0.4956966 -0.4956966
 [5,] -0.2308919 -0.2308919
 [6,] -0.5086596 -0.5086596
 [7,] -0.3042351 -0.3042351
 [8,] -0.1685660 -0.1685660
 [9,] -0.6570624 -0.6570624
[10,] -0.8632634 -0.8632634
```

So as you can see from the output above, for sure one decomposition of $X$ is $X=UDV^T$.  Likewise, calculating $UU^TY$ is equivalent to calculating $X\hat\beta$ where $\hat\beta=(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$.  So this solution really just pertains to validating your second question about whether or not what you are doing is correct.

Comment: Thanks for this example. I checked your code and it does indicate that U matrix is Nxp, and V matrix is pxp and D matrix is pxp, where N=10, and p=2. However, since I find reference about getting U as square matrix, such as here (http://web.mit.edu/be.400/www/SVD/Singular_Value_Decomposition.htm) I am still a bit confused.